# Why does updating the html content break my event handler functions? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, event-handling, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I am attempting to reverse engineer the AngularJS [tutorial example of a "Todo List"](http://angularjs.org/) using only jQuery/native JS. I am doing this simply as a learning experience, as it is clear that AngularJS is a superior method for building this kind of an app.

[Here is my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UmPLH/)

Not all functionality is in place yet (e.g. archiving finished tasks) but most of what I have put in place works as it should. The issue at hand involves the event handlers for clicking on the `.unchecked` and `.checked` checkboxes. They work as intended when the document loads the first time, but after the `updateToDo()` function is called, those event handlers fail to manipulate the DOM even though it contains elements with classes that should trigger the handlers when clicked.

I've reviewed the code several times, making use of the JS console, ensuring no typos were to blame, and even rearranging the placement of the functions to allow for the target elements to be rendered when the functions are executed.

Some pertinent excerpts from the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="holder">
        <h3 id="title"><span id="currentnum"></span> of <span id="totalnum"></span> showing.</h3>
 <a href="#" id="archive">[Archive]</a>

        <br />
        <ul id="ul-list" class="ul-list">
            <!-- Here goes the list -->
        </ul>
        <br />
        <input type="text" placeholder="New Todo" id="textinput" />
        <button id="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//Add new items to ToDoList
    var addTodo = function (input) {
        ToDoList.list.push({
            text: input,
            done: false
        });
        updateTodo();
    };

    // Update view to reflect model
    var updateTodo = function () {
        var listText = "";
        var listLength = getListLength();
        console.log(ToDoList.list);

        for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
            listText += "<input type='checkbox' class='unchecked' /><li id='li-list-" + i + "' class='li-list'>" + ToDoList.list[i].text + "</li><br />";
        }

        $("#ul-list").html(listText);
        updateCounter();
    };
```

Event Handlers:

```
$('input.unchecked').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked unchecked');
        $('.checked').next('.li-list').css({
            'text-decoration': 'line-through',
                'color': 'gray'
        });
        $('.unchecked').next('.li-list').css({
            'text-decoration': 'none',
                'color': '#000'
        });
        updateCounter();
    });

    $('input.checked').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('checked unchecked');
        $('.checked').next('.li-list').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
        $('.unchecked').next('.li-list').css('text-decoration', 'none');
        updateCounter();
    });

    //Button action
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var input = $('#textinput').val();
        if (input !== "") {
            addTodo(input);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the HTML is in reality *replacing* the HTML. That means removing everything that's in the DOM, event handlers included.

Then the new HTML is added, effectively replacing the old HTML, only that the old event handlers haven't been re-added.

A common solution to this problem is to use event delegation. That is, add an event handler in a node that's a parent of what's getting replaced, and listen for events that have an `e.target` (that is, the node that the event originated on) which satisfies the child node you want.

The difference is that new nodes will still match the check for nodes like such and such, and won't be removed when replacing their children.

You can read some more about event delegation here: [Getting Over jQuery](http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2013/07/09/getting-over-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I gave you the selected answer because you answered first, and in fact I used your answer to do some quick research about the `.delegate()` and `.on()` jQuery methods that led me to correct the problem with code that looks almost identical to the example provided by @Tieson

Answer (score 1):

Your delegates will only be attached to those elements that are present when the DOM is created. If you want dynamic elements to be targeted, you have to add the delegate to a parent element that **isn't** replaced and then filter down to the actual elements you want to target; you also need to use the `.on()` function, like so:

```
$("#ul-list").on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){ })
```

It's also worth mentioning that the HTML you are generating for your list is invalid - a `ul` or `ol` element can only have `li` elements as it's immediate children.

Comment: I see! Thanks to you and @Nico as well. I was not aware of this effect on dynamically generated html. [Here is an updated JSFiddle with the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/M38YY/).

I used nearly the exact syntax as you provided, with the exception of `.checked` and `.unchecked` as the selectors, although these could be grouped into a single function with a conditional statement that carries out a different handler for the given class.

Comment: As for my invalid html, I'm not overly concerned with syntax errors in this instance, but for learning purposes, what would you recommend I do to prepend a checkbox to those list items?

Comment: @BrianS You don't, if you want your markup to be valid. Use a `<label>` with your checkboxes if you want something to strikeout. So you'd have something like `<li><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></li>`, and you can use `.closest()` to find it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$(document.body).on('click', #btn", function() {....} );
```

The problem is that browser doesnt bind new elements